# display: flex not working in CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In my template

```
<div class="summary-card">    
    <div ng-repeat="cardData in summaryCardsCtrl.summaryDetails">
        <div ng-switch ="cardData.uniqueCardsDataFlag">
            <div ng-switch-when=true>

                <div style="background-color: red; width:170px; height: 50px;">
                    1111111
                </div>
            </div>
            <div ng-switch-default>
                <div class="cool-grid">
                    <div style="background-color: blue; width:170px; height: 50px;">
                        222222
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

`ng-switch will be true only once; hence the red div will be only one and the rest will be blue`.

CSS looks like:

```
div.summary-card {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px 10px 15px 0px;
    display: flex;
}
.cool-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Now, they all stack up on top of each other.

[image]

But I want them to show like:

[image]

I am not sure how to give classes inside such a ng-repeat to make them look like this.

**so that only the blue divs inside ng-switch-default wraps around each other and not around the red div.**

Please help.

**UPDATE**

Rendered HTML looks like:

```html
<div class="summary-card">    
        <!----><div ng-repeat="cardData in summaryCardsCtrl.summaryDetails">
         <div ng-switch="cardData.uniqueCardsDataFlag">
          <!----><div ng-switch-when="true">
<!--            <div ng-include="'......'"></div> -->

           <div style="background-color: red; width:170px; height: 50px;">
            1111111
           </div>
          
          </div><!---->
          <!---->
            </div>
        </div><!----><div ng-repeat="cardData in summaryCardsCtrl.summaryDetails">
         <div ng-switch="cardData.uniqueCardsDataFlag">
          <!---->
          <!----><div class="cool-grid" ng-switch-default="">
<!--                <div  ng-include="'.....'"></div> -->
      <div style="background-color: blue; width:170px; height: 50px;">
       222222
      </div>
             </div><!---->
            </div>
        </div><!----><div ng-repeat="cardData in summaryCardsCtrl.summaryDetails">
         <div ng-switch="cardData.uniqueCardsDataFlag">
          <!---->
          <!----><div class="cool-grid" ng-switch-default="">
<!--                <div  ng-include="'.....'"></div> -->
      <div style="background-color: blue; width:170px; height: 50px;">
       222222
      </div>
             </div><!---->
            </div>
        </div><!----><div ng-repeat="cardData in summaryCardsCtrl.summaryDetails">
         <div ng-switch="cardData.uniqueCardsDataFlag">
          <!---->
          <!----><div class="cool-grid" ng-switch-default="">
<!--                <div  ng-include="'......'"></div> -->
      <div style="background-color: blue; width:170px; height: 50px;">
       222222
      </div>
             </div><!---->
            </div>
        </div><!---->  
    </div>
```

Comment: Share the rendered HTML, please.

Comment: @cale_b Please see the updated rendered details.

Answer (score 1):

I've knocked up a simplified version that I think does what you're after.

The outer div needs `flex-wrap:wrap`, the red one needs to have its flex-basis set at 100%. The blue ones will then wrap to the next column and be laid out out according to whatever rules you give them...

```
#outer{
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid grey;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:space-between;
  width:500px;
}

#red{
  background-color:red;
  width:100px;
  flex-basis:100%;
}
.blue{
  flex-basis:25%;
  width:100px;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

[codepen here](https://codepen.io/jenko3000/pen/XqVqeg)

Comment: they do, I've updated the codepen to make it more clear https://codepen.io/jenko3000/pen/XqVqeg

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the bootstrap grid to get the layout you want. You do not have to use display flex for that.

Below is an example fot the layout using bootstrap grid

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
 
}
.red{
  background-color:red;
   padding: 10px;
   margin: 10px;
   height: 120px;
}
.blue{
  background-color: blue;
   padding: 10px;
   margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" class="">
       <div class="red">
            sd
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="blue">
            sd
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="blue">
            sd
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="blue">
            sd
            </div>
          </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: he is not using bootstrap and please see render html

Comment: yes. Just showing an alternate easy way to achieve that layout

Comment: Why load an entire framework like bootstrap just to accomplish something that should be do-able with some simple CSS?

Comment: @suzan I understand, but somehow, can I achieve the same without doing this framework level change with some css rules?

Comment: if you want the same without adding another CSS framework, i think the answer By @will

Answer (score 0):

Check this layout. I have used flex for generating it

U can change the height of red block accordingly

Also the blue blocks will wrap automatically to next row, when it doesn't get enough width on the same line

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.summary-card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.left-sec,
.right-sec {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.right-sec {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="summary-card">

  <div class="left-sec">
    <!---->
    <div ng-repeat="cardData in summaryCardsCtrl.summaryDetails">
      <div ng-switch="cardData.uniqueCardsDataFlag">
        <!---->
        <div ng-switch-when="true">
          <!--            <div ng-include="'......'"></div> -->

          <div style="background-color: red; width:170px; height: 50px;">
            1111111
          </div>

        </div>
        <!---->
        <!---->
      </div>
    </div>
    <!---->
  </div>
  <div class="right-sec">

      <div ng-repeat="cardData in summaryCardsCtrl.summaryDetails">
        <div ng-switch="cardData.uniqueCardsDataFlag">
          <!---->
          <!---->
          <div class="cool-grid" ng-switch-default="">
            <!--                <div  ng-include="'.....'"></div> -->
            <div style="background-color: blue; width:170px; height: 50px;">
              222222
            </div>
          </div>
          <!---->
        </div>
      </div>
      <!---->
      <div ng-repeat="cardData in summaryCardsCtrl.summaryDetails">
        <div ng-switch="cardData.uniqueCardsDataFlag">
          <!---->
          <!---->
          <div class="cool-grid" ng-switch-default="">
            <!--                <div  ng-include="'.....'"></div> -->
            <div style="background-color: blue; width:170px; height: 50px;">
              222222
            </div>
          </div>
          <!---->
        </div>
      </div>


    <!---->
    <div ng-repeat="cardData in summaryCardsCtrl.summaryDetails">
      <div ng-switch="cardData.uniqueCardsDataFlag">
        <!---->
        <!---->
        <div class="cool-grid" ng-switch-default="">
          <!--                <div  ng-include="'......'"></div> -->
          <div style="background-color: blue; width:170px; height: 50px;">
            222222
          </div>
        </div>
        <!---->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!---->
</div>
```

Comment: But how can the  classes be added with ng-repeat as the problem states ?